# SignalR connection request does not send cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cookies, signalr

I am building a web application using ASP.NET Web API and SignalR. I have a pretty good understanding of HTTP but this problem is beyond me.

Currently, I am setting a cookie on all AJAX requests to this API. Subsequent AJAX requests to the API send the cookie without issue.

However, I would like this cookie to also be used in the SignalR requests that establish a connection, but according to Chrome, the cookie is not being sent in these requests. I have the cookie set as HTTPOnly. Currently, everything is running locally; all requests go to `localhost:port`. The domain on the cookie is being set to `localhost` as well.

My SignalR connections look like this:

```
var connection = $.connection("/updates");
/* set handlers here */
connection.start(function () {
    console.log("connection started!");
});
```

It seems as if Chrome thinks this is a CORS request and is withholding the cookies. The requests are on the same domain however, so this does not make much sense.

Comment: Are you requesting the cookie from your hub? Like: cookie = Context.RequestCookies["sid"];?

Comment: I'm using plain old PersistantConnections. The issue turned out to be how my cookies were configured. See my answer. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I don't understand cookies well enough. Browsers seem to have trouble handling TLDs like `localhost` as the cookie domain. Therefore, I left the domain undefined, so that the cookie will default to the domain of the request.

However, the path parameter needed to be set to `/` in order to make sure the cookie is sent in all requests.

Once I made these changes, everything worked as expected, and my cookies were plainly visible in SignalR.