# Create http only cookie from Signalr Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to create HTTP only cookie from Signalr Hub because of my client's requirements.

But Cookie class from Signalr doesn't allow to create HTTP only cookie.

Anybody knows how do I create HTTP only cookie and append it to Signalr request/response use?

Comment: Why not the client request a web API or MVC action that writes the cookie in a response and you can instruct the client to do that from your signalR hub

Comment: @HaithamShaddad - because of client's requirement I have to set cookie from Signalr hub.another issue is how do I send cookie from Signalr client to Signalr server?

Comment: Cookies should be sent automatically from the client, have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742579/signalr-cookies-not-sent-from-client

Comment: I've already tried that.I had created a cookie from my webapi and then tried to send to Signalr server from client using this option.I've also change signalr version to 2.2.1.But not working